# How to stop calling data() function for the child items in a tree view initially

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I am implementing a tree view where initially I am showing all the parents, all the child items are collapsed.
but when initially I show my tree view, data() function is calling for all the items which are collapsed(childs) also.
How to prevent the data function calling for collapsed child items also, I want my data function to be called only for the items which are visible.

I have customized QAbstractItemModel, QTreeView and using them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But maybe your model designed in the way it tells the view to fetch more data? How the model looks like?

Comment: I have re-implemented below functions in my model.      data(), setData(),  virtual QModelIndex index( int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex() ) const;
    virtual QModelIndex parent( const QModelIndex &index ) const;
    int rowCount( const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex() ) const;
    virtual bool hasChildren ( const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() ) const;
    int columnCount( const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex() ) const { return m_columnCount; }

Comment: Please add your code to your question instead of placing it in the comments. It's hard to read without indentation.

Comment: It would be useful to include the complete code of the model, not only tell use which methods you've reimplemented.